# Applying fog glow to textures

Tags: rendering, texturing, compositing-nodes, render-passes

[image]

[image]

The image above is one of my previous renders and the one below is my recent render. As you can see, I applied a texture to each of the objects in the model, however the in the previous render the fog glow around the texture is superior to that of the image below. I am unable to recreate the same effect in the latest render and all attempt to do so result in the diffuse material also being affected by the Glare Filter. Can anyone help me out here?

This is my setup:

[image]

This is one of my references:

[image]

Comment: You need to put the object(s) you are applying the Glare Node to on a separate Render Layer. Then apply the Glare node to that layer.

Comment: @Dontwalk yes, already did that, but as you can see, it's affecting the diffuse materials on that layer too

Comment: Make sure you don't confuse render layers with scene layers, if you have two render layers then it is impossible that your compositing affects the other one if you set the effects before mixing the passes. If you wish to use compositing on a particular object or material within a single layer you will have to use object/material ID.

Comment: @Yvain They are on separate render layers (check my files)